# How do I access the name of the action defined in a Java key binding?

Tags: java, key-bindings

This code works well for me to make key bindings more pleasant, via calls such as those that follow:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke;

public abstract class KeyBoundButton extends JButton{

  public abstract void action(ActionEvent e);

  public KeyBoundButton(String actionMapKey, int key, int mask)
  {
    Action myAction = new AbstractAction()
    {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        action(e);
      }
    };  

    setAction(myAction);

    getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
                  .put(getKeyStroke(key, mask),actionMapKey);
    getActionMap().put(                        actionMapKey, myAction);

  }
}
```

Typical call:

```
button = new KeyBoundButton("WHATEVER", VK_X, CTRL_DOWN_MASK) 
{
  @Override 
  public void action(ActionEvent e)
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ctrl-X was pressed");
  }
};
```

But I don't have a clue how to use the action name, `WHATEVER`, either intelligently or otherwise, elsewhere in a program. (I don't see any purpose for it other than documentation.)

I wondered about `button.getActionCommand()` but it returns `null`, even if I insert this line after `action(e)` in the class definition:

```
    setActionCommand(actionMapKey);
```

How would I access the action name somewhere in a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the `setActionCommand(actionMapKey);` after `setAction` inside the constructor not inside action performed..Then you can access the value using `getActionCommand()`

```
 public KeyBoundButton(String actionMapKey, int key, int mask)
  {
    Action myAction = new AbstractAction()
    {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        action(e);
      }
    };  

    setAction(myAction);
 setActionCommand(actionMapKey);//like this
 System.out.println(getActionCommand());
    getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
                  .put(getKeyStroke(key, mask),actionMapKey);
    getActionMap().put(                        actionMapKey, myAction);

  }
```

Comment: If I add the line below to just after `setAction`, it displays `<null>`.  `System.out.println("<" + getActionCommand() + ">");`

Comment: @DSlomer64 Now try I have added after `setAction`.It will work now

Comment: Thanks. I would swear that I had already tried that once before, but whatever I did, I obviously didn't do it right.

Comment: P.S. I can refer to it like so: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ctrl-X was pressed " + getActionCommand());` in the definition of `button`.